# How would I add the 5px padding across all the lines?

Tags: html, css, jekyll, padding, blogs

How would I add the padding across all the lines? It only shows up on the first line.

[image]

Here's my code:

```css
code {
  color: black;
  background-color: darken($background-color, 5%);
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: eventhough the default is 0, can you try giving the padding a value of 0 in the css maybe that will work?

Comment: Sadly it didn't work.

Comment: It is impossible for us to help with the information provided. What is the HTML mark up? Did you use the inspector and look and see where the padding is from, it will point you to where it comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, let's say that you have the following code, you will notice that there is no extra space as you wanted in the result.

And I actually noticed that indentation matters check out the snippet below, to see how I wrote it in my editor.

[image: result]

```css
  pre code {
        background-color: #eee;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<pre><code>pre code {
        background-color: #eee;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        display: block;
        padding: 20px;
}
</code></pre>
```

And check this out with some indentation. The result is going to change and two new lines are to be added. One at the top and one at the bottom.

[image: result2]

```css
 pre code {
        background-color: #eee;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        display: block;
        /* padding: 20px; */
    }
```

```html
<pre><code>
        pre code {
        background-color: #eee;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        display: block;
        padding: 20px;
}
       </code></pre>
```

The two new lines are called `textNode` they are added by the browser since there is space in the line. And every space you add is called `textNode`

I don't understand the process behind it completely but I think it is the reason you are having some extra lines or paddings you didn't even add.

And that's how it looks on the browser

[image: result3]

and here is the result after removing the extra spacing.

[image: result4]

---

### **Edit**

---

Based upon your request.
Here is how the code looks in my editor

[image: result5]

and here is how it looks in the browser

[image: result]

To add padding from all sides as I understood from your code all you need to do is to add the following.

```css
/* CSS */
pre code {
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<pre class="myPre">
<code class="myCode">pre code { 
background-color: #eee;
border: 1px solid #999;
display: block;
padding: 20px;
}</code></pre>
```

Another way to avoid all of this hassle is to use `white-space: pre-line;` here is how it looks on my editor.

[image: result7]

```css
pre code {
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  display: block;
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<pre class="myPre">
    <code class="myCode">code {
        background-color: #eee; 
        border: 1px solid #999;
        display: block;
        padding: 20px;
            }
</code></pre>
```

And there you go, the padding is working as expected make sure you are wrapping the `code` with a `pre` in order to get it to work correctly.

If that wasn't what you request do please let me know again. I will do my best to help you out.

Comment: Alright, I fixed it. But now I have a new problem. I've edited my post above.

Comment: Hi There, did you wrap your `code` with a `pre` if you did all you need is to give `code` some padding and it will work., I will edit my code at the end and show you how I did it and how it looks like on my editor too.

Answer (score -1):

There is most likely padding in the code for the text in the code blocks. Could you  try making that padding 0? I would post the code for it as well for a better chance of finding the issue.

Comment: This is what I have:
https://i.imgur.com/6IlxTAc.png
https://i.imgur.com/29c9UQV.png